# Can't find the right selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to have a class call a function when it's clicked but it's not working.

```
$('.container_vragen').click(appendContainerVragenToContent_vragen);
```

with this code the function is called, but I want to call the action on `.container_vragen` only when it's in the div `#geregeld`

```
$('.container_vragen' , '#geregeld').click(appendContainerVragenToContent_vragen);
```

And when I define that `.container_vragen` is inside `#geregeld` it does not call the function `appendContainerVragenToContent_vragen`

What's the right selector for this?

Comment: Define "it does not work".

Comment: Does the DOM change after your call ?

Comment: With the second code it does not call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to use the power of selectors :

```
$('#geregeld .container_vragen').click(appendContainerVragenToContent_vragen);
```

But note that this won't work if the DOM changes after you call. If you want to allow this, use

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#geregeld .container_vragen', appendContainerVragenToContent_vragen);
```

Comment: Could you explain why it won't work if the DOM (that's the `.container_vragen` class right?) changes? Anyway, you're code does work, but I'm wondering what's the difference.

Comment: Suppose you call the first line when there is not yet any `'#geregeld .container_vragen'` element. Then the jQuery set is empty and `click` does nothing. The second form, using `on`, tests the selector each time you click, not just when you initially call the binding function `on`.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thanks a lot. This simple code was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `string` instead of `DOM` object in the context, find more about selector and context [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

*Change to*

```
$('.container_vragen' , $('#geregeld')).click(appendContainerVragenToContent_vragen);
```

or using [**descendant selector**](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
 $('#geregeld .container_vragen').click(appendContainerVragenToContent_vragen);
```